# Leer datos del puerto serial cuelga mi GUI

Tags: python, hilos, pyqt5, pyqt, pyserial

Estoy haciendo una aplicación de control de accesos en Python. Tengo una ventana en PyQt5, la cual lleva un reloj que va corriendo y una conexión a un Arduino que es el que leerá mediante su correspondiente NFC una tarjeta.

El caso es que para que las dos tareas (reloj y NFC) funcionen a la vez, lo estoy intentando con 2 timer, uno para el reloj y otro para Arduino, pero en cuanto pongo la del Arduino se me queda colgado el programa. Si en ese tiempo hago lecturas de tarjeta, aparentemente funciona, pero el GUI se queda bloqueado. Os pego aquí el código a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano.

```
import sys, re, time
import serial
import os.path #Comprobar si la BBDD existe
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QDialog, QMessageBox, 
QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from time import localtime, strftime


#Clase heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventanas)
class Ventana(QDialog):
    #Método constructor de la clase
    def __init__ (self):
        #Iniciar objeto QDialog
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        #Cargar configuración del archivo .ui en el objeto
        uic.loadUi('fichajes.ui', self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Tick)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.timer2 = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.LeerTarjeta)
        self.timer2.start(1000)

        self.btnSalir.clicked.connect(self.Salir)
        #self.lblTime.setText(strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime()))
        #self.lblDate.setText(strftime("%d-%m-%Y", localtime()))


    def Tick(self):
        # get the current local time from the PC
        self.lblTime.setText(strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime()))
        self.lblDate.setText(strftime("%d-%m-%Y", localtime()))

    def LeerTarjeta(self):

        # Conectar con Arduino
        try:
            arduino = serial.Serial('COM4', 9600)
            rawString = arduino.readline()
            print(rawString)
            self.txtUID.setText(str(rawString)[7:-5])
            self.Tick()
        except Exception:
            # Colocado Exception para que detecte el CTRL + C como interrupciÃ³n
            print("Problem with the serial port" + Exception)

    def Salir(self):
        exit()

# Instancia para iniciar la aplicación (obligatorio pasar argumento)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
ventana.show()

#Ejecutar la aplicación
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En esta respuesta voy a mostrar 2 soluciones:

1. La primera es implementar un hilo dedicada a la lectura del serial ya que en general no se sabe cuando se tiene la data, y en tu caso veo que estas abriendo el puerto cada periodo de tiempo.

---

```
import sys

import serial
import threading

from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets

class Helper(QtCore.QObject):
    textSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

def leer_puerto(port, baudrate, helper):
    arduino = serial.Serial(port, baudrate)
    while arduino.isOpen():
        rawString = arduino.readline()
        helper.textSignal.emit(str(rawString)[7:-5])


class Ventana(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(Ventana, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('fichajes.ui', self)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.btnSalir.clicked.connect(self.close)
        port = "COM4"
        self.helper = Helper()
        self.helper.textSignal.connect(self.txtUID.setText)
        threading.Thread(target=leer_puerto, args=(port, 9600, self.helper), daemon=True).start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def tick(self):
        self.lblTime.setText(QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"))
        self.lblDate.setText(QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toString("dd-MM-yyyy"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Ventana()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

2. La segunda solucion es usar QSerialPort, esta clase es especializada en el manejo del serial y amigable con el eventloop de Qt.

---

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSerialPort


class Ventana(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__ (self, parent=None):
        super(Ventana, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi('fichajes.ui', self)
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.btnSalir.clicked.connect(self.close)
        port = "COM4"
        self.arduino = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort(port, self)
        self.arduino.setBaudRate(QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Baud9600)
        self.arduino.readyRead.connect(self.onReadyRead)

        if not self.arduino.open(QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.ReadWrite):
            # http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#SerialPortError-enum
            print("Problema con el puerto", self.arduino.error())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def tick(self):
        self.lblTime.setText(QtCore.QTime.currentTime().toString("hh:mm:ss"))
        self.lblDate.setText(QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toString("dd-MM-yyyy"))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onReadyRead(self):
        while self.arduino.canReadLine():
            rawString = self.arduino.readLine()
            self.txtUID.setText(str(rawString)[7:-5])

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.arduino.isOpen():
            self.arduino.close()
        super(Ventana, self).closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ventana = Ventana()
    ventana.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: No acabo de entender qué significa @QtCore.pyqtSlot(), ni tampoco el uso de closeEvent, ¿una ayuda más?

Comment: @visent primero vayamos con closeEvent, ese metodo es llamado un instante antes de cerrarse la ventana,por lo que en mi ejemplo estoy señalando que se cierre el puerto serial justo antes de cerrarse la ventana, por otro lado PyQt es un binding de Qt,y Qt usa el MOC para hacer las conecciones de las señales y los slots, en C++ uno puede declarar un slot, en PyQt el equivalente es el uso del decorador, esto hace que la coneccion sea mas ligera haciendo que consuma menos recurso.

Comment: Creo que eso son 10 pasos más adelante de lo que yo sé, ¿podrías indicarme algún libro donde se traten este tipo de cosas y poderlas ver con más calma?

Comment: @visent lee la documentacion

Comment: ¿Qué documentación? No veo nada, lo siento, debo estar algo espeso hoy.

Comment: @visent la documentación de Qt: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html

Answer (score -1):

1) El modo más sencillo para usar un hilo es instanciar un objeto de la clase Thread con una función objetivo y hacer una llamada a su método start().

```
import threading
def worker():
    """funcion que realiza el trabajo en el thread"""
    print 'Estoy trabajando para Genbeta Dev'
    return
threads = list()
for i in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

2) Ver que los paremetros concuerden con cualquier tipo de objeto puede ser pasado como parámetro a un thread.

```
import threading
def worker(count):
    """funcion que realiza el trabajo en el thread"""
    print "Este es el %s trabajo que hago hoy para Genbeta Dev" % count
    return
threads = list()
for i in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(i,))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

3) La salida del anterior ejemplo sería como la que sigue saldria los siguiente código de aceptación:

```
Este es el 0 trabajo que hago hoy para Genbeta Dev
Este es el 1 trabajo que hago hoy para Genbeta Dev
Este es el 2 trabajo que hago hoy para Genbeta Dev
```

4) por cierto me olvidaba que se pueden usar argumentos para nombrar los threads que creamos aunque no es necesario. Cada instancia de la clase Thread tiene un nombre asigno por defecto.

Nombrar los threads puede ser útil por ejemplo, a la hora de clarificar nuestro código.

```
import threading
import time
def worker():
    print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Lanzado'
    time.sleep(2)
    print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Deteniendo'
def servicio():
    print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Lanzado'
    print threading.currentThread().getName(), 'Deteniendo'
t = threading.Thread(target=servicio, name='Servicio')
w = threading.Thread(target=worker, name='Worker')
z = threading.Thread(target=worker)
w.start()
z.start()
t.start()
```

5) Por lo siguiente mostramos La salida del código anterior sería:

```
Worker Lanzado
Thread-1 Lanzado
Servicio Lanzado
Worker Deteniendo
Thread-1 Deteniendo
Servicio Deteniendo
```

6) Si vamos a depurar o logear algo relacionado con los threads lo mejor es que utilicemos el módulo logging para ello colocamos el siguiente comandos:

```
import threading
import logging
import time
logging.basicConfig( level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(levelname)s] - %(threadName)-10s : %(message)s')
def worker():
    logging.debug('Lanzado')
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.debug('Deteniendo')
w = threading.Thread(target=worker, name='Worker')
w.start()
```

7) El módulo logging soporta la inclusión del nombre del hilo de forma nativa, la salida de uno de los mensajes anteriores sería parecido a esto:

```
[DEBUG] - Worker : Lanzado
```

8) Para levantar un thread como daemon solo tenemos que invocar a su método setDaemon() pasándole el argumento True.

```
import threading
import logging
import time
logging.basicConfig( level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='[%(levelname)s] - %(threadName)-10s : %(message)s')
def daemon():
    logging.debug('Lanzado')
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.debug('Deteniendo')
d = threading.Thread(target=daemon, name='Daemon')
d.setDaemon(True)
d.start()
```

**conclusión:**

Hoy hemos un hecho un primer contacto con el módulo threading de Python y hemos aprendido a usar el objeto logging para usar mensajes de depurado con nuestros hilos.

Comment: Su respuesta responde la OP?, por favor lea [answer] y pase el [tour], aqui nadie ha pedido un tutorial, y si lo hiciera seria off-topic.