# ¿Cómo gestionar ventanas en aplicación MDI?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Partimos de 3 "subaplicaciones" ya hechas, una de ellas ya la comenté por aquí [Leer datos del puerto serial cuelga mi GUI](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178644/leer-datos-del-puerto-serial-cuelga-mi-gui), cada una de ellas formada por su archivo .pyw y su correspondiente archivo .ui que corresponde a la ventana diseñada.

No encuentro la forma de crear una ventana .ui con su .pyw que me haga de menú para poder seleccionar cualquiera de las 3 subaplicaciones que funcionen de manera independiente.

Entiendo que una forma podría ser poner todo el código junto en un único archivo .pyw e ir gestionándolo, pero no lo veo, o igual sí sería lo correcto. No sé, ahora mismo estoy desorientado.

¿Alguna ayuda con esto?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿La idea no es usar [QMdiArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mdi-example.html) sino solo crear un lanzador? Si es así depende de si quieres ejecutar cada aplicación en un proceso distinto (podrías usar `QProcess` o incluso `subprocess`) o usar un mismo proceso para todas las posibles ventanas y el lanzador (en cuyo caso procederías como con cualquier subventana, solo tendrías que importar los módulos que las implementan, instanciarlas y llamar a `show` por ejemplo)

Comment: Un QMdiArea podría ser interesante, pero lo dejo como futura mejora. Ahora se trata de una ventana con 3 botones y cada botón que lance por separado cualquiera de las otras tres aplicaciones, es decir, no a la interfaz gráfica, si no al .pyw correspondiente. Y ahí es donde me bloqueo.

Comment: @visent usa `QProcess.startDetached("/path/of/your.pyw")`

Comment: He utilizado esa opción y no me hace nada, aquí el código del proceso de inicio que es corto `class Ventana(QDialog):
    # Variable global
    global abierta

    # Método constructor de la clase
    def __init__(self):
        # Iniciar objeto QDialog
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        # Cargar configuración del archivo .ui en el objeto
        uic.loadUi('inicio.ui', self)

        # Asignar evento botón a método
        self.btnFichajes.clicked.connect(self.Fichajes)
       
    def Fichajes(self):
        QProcess.startDetached("fichajes.pyw")`

Comment: ¿Alguna idea de por qué falla el anterior código?